# Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Supposed I have a Docker container and a folder on my host `/hostFolder`. Now if I want to add this folder to the Docker container as a volume, then I can do this either by using `ADD` in the `Dockerfile` or mounting it as a volume.

So far, so good.

Now `/hostFolder` contains a sub-folder, `/hostFolder/subFolder`.

I want to mount `/hostFolder` into the Docker container (whether as read-write or read-only does not matter, works both for me), but I do **NOT** want to have it included `/hostFolder/subFolder`. I want to exclude this, and I also want the Docker container be able to make changes to this sub-folder, without the consequence of having it changed on the host as well.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: It does work via tmpfs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911280/3419751

Answer (score 630, accepted):

Using docker-compose I'm able to use node_modules locally, but ignore it in the docker container using the following syntax in the `docker-compose.yml`

```
volumes:
   - './angularApp:/opt/app'
   - /opt/app/node_modules/
```

So everything in `./angularApp` is mapped to `/opt/app` and then I create another mount volume `/opt/app/node_modules/` which is now empty directory - even if in my local machine `./angularApp/node_modules` is not empty.

Comment: It works but i cannot remove these dirs inside container
For example: i need to replace `/opt/app/node_modules/` with another directory with same name. Error happens: 'volume busy'

Comment: Please note that order is important: if your image had files under `/opt/app/node_modules/` they will be ignored if you mount it after the parent directory. For exemple, if you want to include modules in the image, but be able to refresh it later, you would list volumes in this order: `- /opt/app/node_modules/` then the parent `- './angularApp:/opt/app'`

Comment: Don't forget the trailing slash! eg. /opt/app/node_modules doesn't work, it will be overwritten by ./angularApp/node_modules

Comment: @kernix you're a king!

Comment: I threw a `9p` virtio mount in the way too, seems the effective user docker tries to expose the volume under needs write permissions to the node_modules folder, even though its empty, and completely unused by anything except the docker container.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that I get the error : `container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused "rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting "..." to rootfs "..." at "/mnt/.../merged/tmp/ui/node_modules" caused "mkdir /mnt/.../merged/tmp/ui/node_modules: read-only file system"""` if someone doesn't have the node_modules folder

Comment: @kernix I've just tried your example. If I do that, then the only thing I see in the "app" folder inside the container is the "node_modules" folder (which is generated by `RUN npm install` in Dockerfile). But no other files show up in the "app" folder inside my container, although I have a bunch of files and folders on my filesystem in that folder the volume points to (angularApp). Should this still work? Win 10 Pro here, Docker version 17.09.0-ce

Comment: @cyrilchampier could you please *cite your sources* on *why the order of listing the volumes in the `docker-compose.yml `affects the way docker is doing the mounts"?* Because the only thing I was able to find is that docker is executing the mounts in [lexicographic order](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26051#issuecomment-242847347). I can not find a reference regarding the way they are listed in `docker-compose` file

Comment: @ira I am not on the subject anymore. From what I remember mounting `- /root - /root/sub` is different than `- /root/sub  - /root`

Comment: on my mac, when I remove node_modules then the container will remove it too; then the trick doesn't work anymore

Comment: @cyrilchampier I believe that this is not true. You can check this by swapping `./angularApp:/opt/app'` and `/app/node_modules/` in the answer above. The results will be the same

Comment: This trick used to work for me, but doesn't seem to anymore, even for the self-same Compose file.  Curious if it also stopped working for others.

Comment: Yep @plinehan, it stopped working for me too. Not sure how to ignore node_modules now.

Comment: thanks! You saved my day!

In case of using simple docker, not compos it would look like:
 `-v $(pwd):/build/ -v /build/node_modules `

Comment: This make my day :)

Comment: Where is this behaviour documented? What `type` is implicitly used (volume, bind, tmpfs or npipe?) and is this behaviour the same as setting `nocopy` in the [volumes *LONG SYNTAX*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3) ?

Comment: Trick still works for me. However, I have trouble wrapping my head around WHY it works. My current understanding is as follows. `.:/app` creates a bind mount, and then `/app/node_modules/` creates an anonymous volume (confirmed with docker inspect) which maps an empty directory from source to the container `/app/node_modules`. Then HOW am I able to use my npm installed packages from my Dockerfile?!

Comment: It doesn't work with `docker-compose 1.25.0-rc3`, file syntax v3.

Comment: I found the document, https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container.`If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above), the directory’s contents are copied into the volume.`

Comment: Good solution. Works for me.

Comment: Note that `node_modules` is NOT updated when you run `docker-compose build`! 

I was expecting that `/opt/app/node_modules/` would always be in-sync with the whatever the container has at this location. But the content is only copied over initially when the volume is created.

So if your `package.json` changes and you re-build the container then the `node_modules` in the volume are not in-sync with the container anymore.

Comment: One strange effect I've noticed with this. If my host machine has no `node_modules` folder, after running the container with volumes as described here, it gets an *empty* `node_modules` folder. It's disconnected from the volume, so changes here are not reflected in the container (good). *However* changes to the parent folder still are, so if I unlink/delete the host's `node_modules` then the *container's* is deleted as well!

Comment: that does work, but the folder inside container is not writable. This method works better https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911280/3419751

Comment: This is excellent. I've been looking for this for quite some time, but never knew how to describe it, such that i came across the correct answer, until today!

Answer (score 186):

If you want to have subdirectories ignored by docker-compose but persistent, you can do the following in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  node_modules:
services:
  server:
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
```

This will mount your current directory as a shared volume, but mount a persistent docker volume in place of your local `node_modules` directory.  This is similar to the answer by @kernix, but this will allow `node_modules` to persist between `docker-compose up` runs, which is likely the desired behavior.

Comment: Named volumes are a superior approach.

Protip: make sure you aren't using a hyphenated volume name. You will spend a small portion of your life in a debug nightmare, only to find out that you were once again fooled by a ridiculous nuance.

Comment: "Note that docker-compose down will kill these persistent volumes." This is not true in Docker for Mac v 17.0.5+ (and possibly older versions). `docker-compose down` will remove the containers, but the volume will persist until you run something like `docker system prune`

Comment: In case someone is interestead to understand *why* using the `node_modules:` named volume "ignores" the `/app/node_modules` in the docker container, may find this post usefull [How docker handles multiple mount types?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47873699/2235814)

Comment: I don't know whether I'm doing something wrong, but if I do this, start the container and then run npm install on the HOST machine, it changes the node_modules inside the CONTAINER too. I can't imagine why anyone would want to do that, but still I'm looking for a cleaner separation.

Comment: any luck @Renra?

Comment: @Renra had the exact same issue, my host machine would constantly write over node_modules even though I had the named volume... caused all sorts of incompatibility issues. 

Gave up on fixing it and worked around it by only copying my src folder instead of the whole repo

Comment: I am setting the env var `ENV NODE_PATH /node_modules` to a dir outside my app. I have a `node_modules_cache:` under the top level `volumes`. I then have `node_modules_cache:/node_modules` under the service. - this seems to work for me.

Comment: I ran into an error: `node_modules is used in service "web" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`. So, I had to use relative dir path, ` - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules`

Answer (score 48):

For those trying to get a nice workflow going where `node_modules` isn't overridden by local this might help.

1. Change your docker-compose to mount an anonymous persistent volume to node_modules to prevent your local overriding it. This has been outlined in this thread a few times.

```
services:
  server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

2. This is the important bit we were missing. When spinning up your stack use `docker-compose -V`. Without this if you added a new package and rebuilt your image it would be using the `node_modules` from your initial docker-compose launch.

```
    -V, --renew-anon-volumes   Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving
                               data from the previous containers.
```

Comment: The note about `--renew-anon-volumes` is an important addition. There are cases where you want to mount your source code folder and exclude the node_modules folder by mounting it as an anonymous volume. The flag avoids the re-using the previously created anonymous volume so that changes to `package.json` will reflect correctly.

Comment: When using this approach, an empty `node_modules` directory is created on the host. How can we avoid that?

Comment: This is the cleanest and easiest solution compared to the others, I'll use this.

Answer (score 29):

To exclude a file, use the following

```
volumes:
   - /hostFolder:/folder
   - /dev/null:/folder/fileToBeExcluded
```

Comment: Perfect solution for what I needed (to NOT map node_modules up to the host because symlink stuff broke on a Windows host). Pointing to /dev/null did not work, but creating a blank directory and mapping it to that worked perfectly and solved the issues I was having - thanks for this idea.

Comment: This doesn't work in Docker for Mac 18.09.0: `Cannot start service xxx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/dev/null\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d15ed56ad020d408c63a1f6a6365dbb88d5d3b78a4605980d3faa9861102ef21/merged\\\" at [...] unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`. Adding a trailing slash didn't help.

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work either on Ubuntu 16.04 with Docker 18.09.3.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. All it does is copy `/dev/null` into the container, as a device file.

Comment: Please note this works only for excluding FILES! /dev/null is a file and so should be the target, the error message is quite clear on this: `Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`. This is not exactly what the OP was looking for, but it was very useful for me, since I needed to exclude a single file.

Answer (score 23):

With the docker command line:

```
docker run \
    --mount type=bind,src=/hostFolder,dst=/containerFolder \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/containerFolder/subFolder \
    ...other-args...
```

The `-v` option may also be used (credit to [Bogdan Mart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder#comment97216954_37898591)), but `--mount` is clearer and [recommended](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-bind-mounts-or-volumes-using-the---mount-flag).

Answer (score 14):

First, using the `ADD` instruction in a Dockerfile is *very* different from using a volume (either via the `-v` argument to `docker run` or the `VOLUME` instruction in a Dockerfile). The `ADD` and `COPY` commands just take a copy of the files at the time `docker build` is run. These files are not updated until a fresh image is created with the `docker build` command. By contrast, using a volume is essentially saying "this directory should not be stored in the container image; instead use a directory on the host"; whenever a file inside a volume is changed, both the host and container will see it immediately.

I don't believe you can achieve what you want using volumes, you'll have to rethink your directory structure if you want to do this.

However, it's quite simple to achieve using `COPY` (which should be preferred to `ADD`). You can either use a `.dockerignore` file to exclude the subdirectory, or you could `COPY` all the files then do a `RUN rm bla` to remove the subdirectory.

Remember that any files you add to image with `COPY` or `ADD` must be inside the build context i.e. in or below the directory you run `docker build` from.

Comment: learn something new every day :-) the COPY and ADD work from the build context (not the host). Would it be possible to use a volume to mask the subFolder? The OP wants to mount the /hostFolder (I think), and make /hostFolder/subFolder disconnected. If there was a VOLUME for each, but only the hostFolder was 'mounted' (-v), would that isolate the subFolder changes to the container?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never tried nesting volumes. I'm not convinced it's a good idea, but I'd have to look into it.

Comment: I can't seem to find an example anywhere of what to put in a `.dockerignore` file to exclude a sub directory (or even a directory). Given that is the stated purpose of the file, it's quite odd.

Comment: once you add any files, they still end up in some layers. So a remove of them will not help you hide them if security sensitive or reduce image size (because they will be in the underlying layers). There are options to `squash` the layers. One is https://github.com/goldmann/docker-squash and another is using `oc ex dockerbuild` from the openshift project.

Answer (score 14):

for the people who also had the issue that the node_modules folder would still overwrite from your local system and the other way around

```
volumes:
  node_modules:
services:
  server:
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules/
```

This is the solution, With the trailing `/` after the node_modules being the fix.

Comment: So this just maps your local `node_modules` folder to be inside `/app/node_modules` folder in the container? So inside the container, we have `/app/node_modules/node_modules`? Why?

Comment: @smac89 read answer above. node_modules is named container, not a host dir folder.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the old solution doesn't work anymore(at least for me).
Creating an empty folder and mapping target folder to it helped though.

```
volumes:
   - ./angularApp:/opt/app
   - .empty:/opt/app/node_modules/
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me either with `docker-compose 1.25.0-rc3`, file syntax v3.

Answer (score 5):

I found this link which saved me: [Working with docker bind mounts and node_modules](https://burnedikt.com/dockerized-node-development-and-mounting-node-volumes/).
This working solution will create a *"exclude"* named volume in docker volumes manager. The volume name *"exclude"* is arbitrary, so **you can use a custom name for the volume intead *exclude***.

```
services:
    node:
        command: nodemon index.js
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/local/app/
            # the volume above prevents our host system's node_modules to be mounted
            - exclude:/usr/local/app/node_modules/

volumes:
    exclude:
```

You can see more infos about volumes in [Official docs - Use a volume with docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me Manjaro Linux, Docker Compose yml has v2.4 at the top since thats the last non-swarm version.
I want to make sure that my snapshots folder on my host is excluded in the docker container.
I do not have volumes section in my docker-compose, keeping it simple:

```
version: "2.4"    
services:
  filerun:
    volumes:
      - $DATAPOOL/users:/user-files
      - /user-files/snapshots/
```

On my host, the folder users/snapshots remains untouched.
Within the container, the folder user-files/snapshots is just an empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

Docker recently added [watch](https://www.docker.com/blog/announcing-docker-compose-watch-ga-release/). It allows for directories to be ignored or excluded.

Say you wanted to exclude `node_modules` directory, you'd do:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./web
          target: /src/web
          ignore:
            - node_modules/
        - action: rebuild
          path: package.json
```

Then start the container with:

```
docker compose watch
```

You can read more about it in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/)

Answer (score 0):

For a file, an env file specifically, that must exist inside the project, I used this solution:

```
    volumes:
      - ./empty.env:/app/.env
```

Where "empty.env" is just an empty file. It helped me to use the same branch in different environments, inside and outside the container.

Answer (score -1):

To exclude a mounted file contained in the volume of your machine, you will have to overwrite it by allocating a volume to this same file.
In your config file:

```
services:
  server:
    build : ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

An example in you dockerfile:

```
# Image Location
FROM node:13.12.0-buster
VOLUME /app/you_overwrite_file
```

Comment: What the OP wants is actually to overwrite/override a directory AT RUNTIME, e.g. when the container starts.

The solution you propose basically deals with BUILDTIME. It seems like a bad idea to try to manage a runtime problem at buildtime. It may work in some cases, but favor answers above.