# return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));

Tags: node.js, opencv

I am getting this error when running an example from OpenCV Node

```
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: /home/sunny/face/build/opencv/v5.0.0/Release/node-v46-linux-x64/opencv.node: undefined symbol: _ZNK2cv9Algorithm5writeERNS_11FileStorageE
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:460:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object. (/home/sunny/face/lib/bindings.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this command, it works fine:

```
npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
```

Answer (score 32):

Try refreshing your installed modules by

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm update
```

I got errors relating to `process.dlopen` when using Gulp and node-sass. Clearing the installed modules fixed the issue for me.

EDIT: Not certain how OpenCV works (or what it actually is), but I presume it handles NodeJS modules similarly to regular NodeJS applications, where you can refresh the module collection.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and it turns out docker is running linux and bcrypt was made on macOS and there is some sort of compatibility issue if you don't run `npm install` within docker.

For me adding a `.dockerignore` file and adding in the `node_module` folders for the project then running `RUN npm install` in the Dockerfile resolved it.

Comment: I dont understand for what we need to add node_modules into .dockerignore.

Comment: This solved my issue. @KevinMendez, node_modules will be taken from the host machine to the docker container. As explained by jawn, there is bcrypt incompatibility between macos vs linux. Docker is in linux. You compiled your code/installed in MacOS. So, you need to force docker to install from within instead of just copying the node_modules from the host machine.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your OpenCV installation, it's probably either missing/can't be found or its not a version supported by the OpenCV node binding. Assuming you're using the [`opencv`](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) module on npm, its readme says that OpenCV versions from v2.3.1 until v3.0.0 are (fully) supported.

Comment: I have installed OpenCV v.2.4.11

Answer (score 2):

My case, I have the `node_modules` on my `.dockerignore`

```
node_modules
upload
export
converage
.git
.tmp
.vscode
.github
.env
```

But I still have to make `docker-compose` be able to ignore the `node_modules` folder.

```yaml
services:
  api:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

`docker-compose` will skip copy `node_modules` which is built for MacOS into Linux container.

[Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder)

Comment: i have the same settings but still having this problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran these commands but to no success

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm update
```

The only thing that helped me was

```
yarn add node-sass
```

Finally my node modules were installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, it works fine:

```
rm -r node_modules
```

And after that use install command again:

```
npm i --save
```