# My code doesn't work when I deploy it to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

My server runs perfectly when I test it locally. However, deploying it to heroku shows the following error:

```
moh@ start /app
2017-05-01T08:04:40.867324+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-05-01T08:04:40.867324+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360564+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:597
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360579+00:00 app[web.1]:   return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360580+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360581+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360582+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360582+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360583+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360584+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360585+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360585+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360586+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360586+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360587+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360588+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360588+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360589+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360590+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360590+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360591+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360592+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.360592+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/usersDetailsRoutes.js:3:14)
2017-05-01T08:04:41.370305+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:41.378189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-05-01T08:04:41.378466+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-05-01T08:04:41.378704+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.2
2017-05-01T08:04:41.378844+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-05-01T08:04:41.378970+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379105+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! moh@ start: `node server.js`
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379285+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the moh@ start script 'node server.js'.
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379537+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379634+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the moh package,
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379743+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379844+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-01T08:04:41.379931+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-05-01T08:04:41.380018+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-01T08:04:41.380103+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs moh
2017-05-01T08:04:41.380233+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-01T08:04:41.380389+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls moh
2017-05-01T08:04:41.380459+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-01T08:04:41.384059+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:41.384227+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-01T08:04:41.384288+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-01T08:04:41.507958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-01T08:04:41.509045+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-01T08:04:41.492959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-01T08:04:43.465939+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-05-01T08:04:45.782290+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:45.782305+00:00 app[web.1]: > moh@ start /app
2017-05-01T08:04:45.782306+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-05-01T08:04:45.782307+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242097+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:597
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242120+00:00 app[web.1]:   return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242121+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242122+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242123+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242123+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242124+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242125+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242125+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242126+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242127+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242127+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242128+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242128+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242129+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242130+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242130+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242131+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242132+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242132+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.242133+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/usersDetailsRoutes.js:3:14)
2017-05-01T08:04:46.250340+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:46.257941+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-05-01T08:04:46.258139+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-05-01T08:04:46.258285+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.2
2017-05-01T08:04:46.258630+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-05-01T08:04:46.258450+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-05-01T08:04:46.258743+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! moh@ start: `node server.js`
2017-05-01T08:04:46.258836+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-05-01T08:04:46.258984+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259080+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the moh@ start script 'node server.js'.
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259251+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the moh package,
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259162+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259342+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259435+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259593+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259672+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs moh
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259762+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259842+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls moh
2017-05-01T08:04:46.259934+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-01T08:04:46.263264+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-01T08:04:46.263441+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-01T08:04:46.263496+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-01T08:04:46.321834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-01T08:04:46.332504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I tried to add the following in the `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js"
    }
```

but I end up with the same error,

here is my `server.js` code:

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes     = require('./routes');
var usersRoute = require('./usersDetailsRoutes');

var morgan = require('morgan');  

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://behrouz:zxcv1234@ds017514.mlab.com:17514/sourceplaze');

require('./config/passport')(passport);


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(passport.initialize());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', usersRoute)

app.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port: ' + port);

module.exports = app;
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: removing the node-modules files and update  check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568243/return-process-dlopenmodule-path-makelongfilename

Comment: can you provide your server.js file

Comment: @MehulPrajapati just updated the question

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you deploy the content of your `node-modules` project folder with a *bcrypt* package that do not work on Heroku.

> Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid
>   ELF header

You should add the `node-modules` folder in your `.gitignore` and just deploy the `package.json` file on the server, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20590261/5156280) suggests.

Comment: I created .gitignore and added the node_modules there and pushed the code again to heroku, after adding all the files again. shouldn't this remove my node_modules folder in heroku?

Comment: Yes I think so. Otherwise just delete the node_modules folder entirely.

Comment: `git rm -rf node_modules` then commit and push.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but just found an option that worked for me

1. npm uninstall bcrypt
2. npm install bcryptjs

Replace bcrypt with bcryptjs everywhere it appears in your code, or just
`const bycrypt = require('bcryptjs')` instead of `const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall bcrypt

npm install bcryptjs
```

Replace `bcrypt` with `bcryptjs` everywhere it appears in your code, or just:

```
const bycrypt = require('bcryptjs')
```

Instead of:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
```