# I received this code error each time I tried to deploy may app on Heroku:code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am new in Heroku and currently building an app with react (Node.js).

While I was able to push successfully my master branch to Heroku and Heroku confirms my app is deployed successfully, yet, the app is not deployed despite that is shows below deploy success message: "Deploy to Heroku".

Below is the error log in Heroku:

```
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702341+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702341+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702341+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702342+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-08T00:45:18.924415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-08T00:45:19.739614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-08T00:45:31.255261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=haksuly1movieapp.herokuapp.com request_id=05cc8ef9-baa5-4af8-8167-ab18ec9fc909 fwd="88.130.53.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-08T00:45:31.413269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=haksuly1movieapp.herokuapp.com request_id=83016251-e4f0-4bf0-87d0-39ecb39ddd3f fwd="88.130.53.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-08T00:46:20.928808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=haksuly1movieapp.herokuapp.com request_id=d243ef5c-56d8-4e22-b095-f3915e338c90 fwd="88.130.53.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-08T00:46:21.142923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=haksuly1movieapp.herokuapp.com request_id=49b1447a-2058-40c8-b85f-6934e1854ebb fwd="88.130.53.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Below is the error log from CLI:

```
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986742+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986743+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986744+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986744+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986745+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986745+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986746+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986746+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986746+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986746+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986747+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986747+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986747+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986748+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2022-02-08T00:45:12.986748+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-08T00:45:13.178543+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-08T00:45:13.264905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-08T00:45:13.273816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-08T00:45:15.956822+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-02-08T00:45:18.232060+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T00:45:18.232080+00:00 app[web.1]: > movie_api@1.0.0 start
2022-02-08T00:45:18.232081+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-02-08T00:45:18.232081+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702302+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702328+00:00 app[web.1]: return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702329+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702330+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702336+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702337+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702338+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702338+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702338+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702339+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702340+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702340+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702340+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702341+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702341+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702341+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2022-02-08T00:45:18.702342+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-08T00:45:18.924415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-08T00:45:19.739614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-08T00:45:31.255261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=haksuly1movieapp.herokuapp.com request_id=05cc8ef9-baa5-4af8-8167-ab18ec9fc909 fwd="88.130.53.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-08T00:45:31.413269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=haksuly1movieapp.herokuapp.com request_id=83016251-e4f0-4bf0-87d0-39ecb39ddd3f fwd="88.130.53.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-08T00:46:20.928808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=haksuly1movieapp.herokuapp.com request_id=d243ef5c-56d8-4e22-b095-f3915e338c90 fwd="88.130.53.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-08T00:46:21.142923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=haksuly1movieapp.herokuapp.com request_id=49b1447a-2058-40c8-b85f-6934e1854ebb fwd="88.130.53.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-08T01:06:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user hakeemkayodesulyman@gmail.com
2022-02-08T01:07:18.099531+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 759fe937 by user hakeemkayodesulyman@gmail.com
2022-02-08T01:07:18.099531+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user hakeemkayodesulyman@gmail.com
2022-02-08T01:07:18.394025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-08T01:07:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-02-08T01:07:21.034913+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-02-08T01:07:22.192406+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T01:07:22.192420+00:00 app[web.1]: > movie_api@1.0.0 start
2022-02-08T01:07:22.192420+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-02-08T01:07:22.192420+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590438+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590456+00:00 app[web.1]: return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590456+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590457+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590458+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590458+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590459+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590459+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590459+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590460+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590460+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590460+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590460+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590460+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590461+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590461+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2022-02-08T01:07:22.590461+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-08T01:07:22.717250+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-08T01:07:22.786581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-08T01:07:22.825527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-08T01:07:25.399388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-02-08T01:07:26.987095+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T01:07:26.987107+00:00 app[web.1]: > movie_api@1.0.0 start
2022-02-08T01:07:26.987107+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-02-08T01:07:26.987108+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610704+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610728+00:00 app[web.1]: return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610729+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610730+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610731+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610731+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610732+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610733+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610733+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610733+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610733+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610734+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610734+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610734+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610735+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610735+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2022-02-08T01:07:27.610735+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-08T01:07:27.789789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-08T01:07:27.876090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have tried all tricks including many suggested here but it has not been helpful.

Of course, my package.json has this script. "start": "node index.js",

Could anyone help with a precise solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My code doesn't work when I deploy it to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716236/my-code-doesnt-work-when-i-deploy-it-to-heroku)

Answer (score 9):

```
npm uninstall bcrypt
npm install bcryptjs
npm install bcrypt

All Good! nodejs v16.16.0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The issue was probably connected the caches in the `Node_Modules`. I fixed this issue by running this in the terminal:

```
$ git rm -r --cached .
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bcryptjs instead of bcrypt

```
$ npm uninstall bcrypt
$ npm install bcryptjs
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answers that involve using bcryptjs! Make sure you also change the require statement(s) to accurately reflect bcryptjs instead of bcrypt.

```
$ npm uninstall bcrypt
$ npm install bcryptjs
```

Above code is what you would need to run in the server component of your app!

Below is the code in the applicable files that require bcrypt but will now require bcryptjs

```
const <name> = require('bcryptjs');
```