# docker composer install RunTimeException /var/www/html/vendor does not exist and could not be created

Tags: php, docker-compose

I have a laravel project. And this is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 90002:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app

php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes_from:
        - app

composer:
    image: composer/composer
    volumes_from:
        - php
    working_dir: /var/www/html

app:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./test-api:/var/www/html
    command: "true"

mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes_from:
        - data
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_DATABASE: user
        MYSQL_USER: uesr
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test

data:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
    command: "true"

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 90003:80
    links:
        - mysql
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
```

And I run this command.

```
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose run --rm composer install # error
```

I got error message

```
[RuntimeException]
/var/www/html/vendor does not exist and could not be created.
```

I tried on my Mac, it's work. But ssh to my service, use the same method, it's not work. Thanks your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing it on Windows, there could be a problem with syncing the files.

If that's the case, you can try to exclude `vendor` dir, see: [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29181032/55075)

Similar problem: [Problem when I execute npm install on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52095320/55075)

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't work on Windows, but it does on macOS, try to:

- Double check the permissions of `/var/www/html` and `vendor` folder on your host as you're potentially sharing this folder from NTFS file-system which doesn't support Linux permissions,
- Check whether files or folder is locked by some running process (e.g. shell or IDE editor).

  For example, using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), select *Find Handle or DLL* from *Find* menu and type folder name.

  I had similar problem which I've described [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2659).