# Merge container files when using docker-sync

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, rsync

I am using docker-sync to speed up the dev environment file updates on my node.js application.

Right now I am trying to cache `npm install` command by moving `package.json` to the image and running `npm install` when the image is created.

**Dockerfile:**

```
ADD ./package.json /app/user/
RUN npm install
```

Then I use the following configuration for docker-sync:

**docker-sync.yml**

```
version: "2"
options:
  verbose: true
syncs:
  appcode-rsync-sync:
    src: './'
    sync_host_ip: 'auto'
    sync_host_port: 10872
    sync_strategy: 'rsync'
    sync_excludes: [ 'public/lib/', 'public/dist/', 'node_modules/']
```

And here is the **docker-compose.yml**:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - appcode-rsync-sync:/app/user:nocopy
    command: grunt

volumes:
  appcode-rsync-sync:
    external: true
```

The problem is that `npm install` installs all the required packages in `node_modules`, `public_lib`, `public_dist` directories, but after mounting the `docker-sync` volume it will remove all those directories from the container (even though they are in the `sync_excludes`.)

I there any option or work around to prevent docker-sync to remove the files which are on the container?

*-I already tried removing `nocopy` but it did not help*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder/37898591#37898591) I modified `docker-compose.yml` to address the problem.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/user/public/lib/
      - /app/user/public/dist/
      - /app/user/node_modules/
      - appcode-rsync-sync:/app/user:nocopy
    command: grunt

volumes:
  appcode-rsync-sync:
    external: true
```

As you can see I added the following volumes:

```
- /app/user/public/lib/
- /app/user/public/dist/
- /app/user/node_modules/
```

Comment: I spend **DAYS** trying to figure this out. thanks!!!