# How docker handles multiple mount types?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This post is somewhat  lenglthy but bear with me for a while...

Suppose you have an app that sits in `/app` in your local (host) filesystem with the following structure

```
app
|-- index.php
|-- foo
|   `-- file-h1
`-- bar
    `-- file-h2
```

Now suppose we have an image (tagged `myrepo/app`) that exploits the following data structure

```
opt
|-- app
|   `-- foo
|       `-- file-c1
```

If we run a container from that image by mounting host's `/app` to container's `/opt/app` as follows

```
docker container run \
-v /app:/opt/app \
myrepo/app
```

The resulting data structure of the container will be the following

```
opt
|-- app
|   |-- index.php
|   |-- foo       
|   |   `-- file-h1          
|   `-- bar
|       `-- file-h2
```

So far, so good...

#### Running container with multiple mounts (both bind-mounts and volumes)

Now, lets say that we want to use **both** a **named volume** called `data` to be mounted on `/opt/app/foo` and a **bind-mount** for mounting `/app` to `/opt/app`

```
docker container run \
-v /app:/opt/app \
-v data:/opt/app/foo
myrepo/app
```

The resulting data structure inside the container will be:

```
opt
|-- app
|   |-- index.php
|   |-- foo       
|   |   `-- file-c1          
|   `-- bar
|       `-- file-h2
```

As it is stated in various posts (like [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26051#issuecomment-242847347) and [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19120#issuecomment-169330570)) the docker mounts are performed in lexicographic order (i.e shortest path first).  According to this, I would expect docker first to execute the bind-mount ( `-v /app:/opt/app`) and then the volume (`-v data:/opt/app/foo`).

Hence, I would *expect* that the contents of host's `/app` would replace/obscure the contents of container's `/opt/app` and thus `file-h1` to be inside `/opt/app/foo`. Finally, `file-h1` would be [copied](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/#tips-for-using-bind-mounts-or-volumes) in the newly created `data` volume and the volume would be mounted on `/opt/app/foo` (so `file-h1` should be shown instead of `file-c1` )

My questions raised when I tried to understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601156/2235814) answer on SO

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally, and with a lot of help by github user [cpuguy83](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19120#issuecomment-352450375), I figured out *what actually docker engine does when we try to run a container that uses multiple mounts of different type (e.g both a **bind-mount** and a **volume**)* as, for instance:

```
docker container run \
-v /app:/opt/app \
-v data:/opt/app/foo
myrepo/app
```

The key point to understand here is that docker executes the process in **two steps** that are done in the following order:

1. First, it creates a new storage-space (i.e. volume) in the host filesystem (`... data/`) for the container to persist files and then (since that newly created volume is empty) it [copies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/#good-use-cases-for-tmpfs-mounts) the container's files (i.e whatever is inside `/opt/app/foo/*`) to the volume's storage location (`... data/`)
2. Then after that, it performs all mounts (binds, volumes, tmpfs mounts, etc... are all lumped together) in lexicographic order (first mounts `/app` to `/opt/app` then `... data/` to `/opt/app/foo`)

So, because of that, when we run the container with the mounts in our example, the docker **first** will copy the `file-c1` to the `... data/` location in the host filesystem and **second** it will mount first the contents of host's `/app` to the container's `/opt/app` and then the host's `... data/` (which contains `file-c1`) to container's `/opt/app/foo` overwriting/obscuring its contents (i.e overwriting `file-h1` with `file-c1`). Therefore, if we take a look inside the running container after the mounts are done, the result will be the following:

```
opt
|-- app
|   |-- index.php
|   |-- foo       
|   |   `-- file-c1          
|   `-- bar
|       `-- file-h2
```

Comment: This was such an unbelievably specific thing I was about to ask on SO and then I came across your question and it explained exactly what I was looking for! I noticed the exact same behavior and couldn't figure out why. Thanks a lot!