# Changing vendor directory can't find files anymore using Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to change the directory of my dependencies on a Symfony 3.4 application.

I need that because I'm working on macOS with Docker and I'd rather have them not shared with the host since the file synchronization is too slow.

The [related documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-vendor-directory), says:

> The change in the composer.json will look like this:
>
> ```
> {
>     "config": {
>         "bin-dir": "bin",
>         "vendor-dir": "/some/dir/vendor"
>     },
> }
> ```

That I did

> Then, update the path to the autoload.php file in app/autoload.php:
>
> ```
> // app/autoload.php
>
> // ...
> $loader = require '/some/dir/vendor/autoload.php';
> ```

I don't have any `autoload.php` file in my `app` directory.
Am I missing something in the doc ?

The application generates the following fatal error:

> Warning: require(/some/dir/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/some/dir/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

I originally created the application with:

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition test "3.*"
```

Comment: Hi, try adding the autoload.php. look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/jasson112/6ba40811473fd5231ea50399e8871a2e is my aoutoload.php maybe it works for you

Comment: There is another way to speed up docker under Mac/Windows. Exclude subdirectories from volume mapping (vendors, cache, bundles). Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder

Comment: @JassonRojas manually adding the file works !

Comment: @VadimAshikhman this is interesting, I'll give it a try. It still requires to move the dependencies elsewhere though :)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY It doesn't, I have working developer environment with docker under Windows which loading time is close to Linux without Docker. I prepared an example here: https://gist.github.com/ashikhman/906d792058e9e6cfd06c5ccad555dac1

Answer (score 7):

1. Open your composer.json file in editor.
2. Look for "autoload-dev" section
3. Remove whole "files" part (if exist)
4. Save file
5. Run `composer install` once again
6. Enjoy the party.

Sample code:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [
      "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3.4, the file `app/autoload.php` is removed so you should:

- replace old vendor path by the new vendor path directly in `web/app.php`, `web/app_dev.php`, bin/console and `var/SymfonyRequirements.php` files
- Rerun the command `$ composer install`

Comment: It worked until I removed the `vendor/` directory from within the app which means it was not using the new `/vendor`

Comment: You should replace it also in `var/SymfonyRequirements.php` file, lines 567 and 568

Comment: I don't understand why it worked (Performance were really better) just before I removed the vendor from the app

Comment: Can you past the ouput of command to more indestand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved doing the next.

### Follow these 3 steps

**1.** First of all, modify `composer.json` to use the new vendor path:

```
"config": {
    ...,
    "vendor-dir": "/app-vendor"
},
```

And remove the next line:

```
"files": ["vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"]
```

**2.** Secondly, if you are using *docker-compose* add a new volume where you'll put your vendors.

```
volumes:
  ...
  - /app-vendor
```

PD: `/app-vendor` is a mounted volume which is now empty directory.

**3.** Lastly, write `require '/app-vendor/autoload.php';` to:

- `my_project_name/bin/console`
- `my_project_name/web/app.php`
- `my_project_name/web/app_dev.php`

PD1: Simply, this line is pointing to the new vendor path.

PD2: It's not necessary to modify any other file (like `var/SymfonyRequirements.php` as I could read).

### Check your changes

Once the changes are ready, remove `vendor/` and also remove the containers to avoid future problems.

Start your new containers and execute `composer install`. Now, `/vendor` will be `/app-vendor`, it won't be in the root folder of the project anymore.

For more details, I'd recommend you to go to my [docker-symfony](https://github.com/apuig1/docker-symfony) repository and check the commits. You'll see a benchmark progression and another tips like cached volumes and non-shared `/cache` && `/logs` folders.

All for Symfony 3.4.