# Make docker-compose ignore folder within volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose for a Rails setup. To sync the files, I've mounted the directory like (some of the code is omitted):

```
app:
    build: .
    command: rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

However, when running the app, I don't want the folder, tmp, to be synced.
Adding the folder to dockerignore only solves the problem when building the docker image.
How can I ignore the tmp folder from being synced between the host and guest when running docker compose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a second volume to a sub-path. It will override the contents of the existing volume. Like so :

```
app:
    build: .
    command: rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./empty-tmp:/app/tmp
```

This will effectively make `/app/tmp` show the contents of `./empty-tmp` on the host system. Instead of showing the contents of `./tmp`

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up doing was to simply map all the folders which I wanted to sync:

```
- ./app:/app/app
- ./lib:/app/lib
- ./log:/app/log
- ./spec:/app/spec
```

Which seems to solve the problem

Comment: yeah - reasonably quick / understandable way to do this - still today.  weird there's no explicit exclusion mechanism in docker-compose (not the volume mapping trick reported in other answers)

Answer (score 3):

This used to be possible as described in [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder). The solutions offered there didn't work for me anymore with docker-compose 1.25.0-rc3, file syntax v3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a data volume to store `tmp`, as data volumes copy in the data from the built docker image before the app directory is mounted

```
volumes:
- .:/app
- /path/to/tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When the guest creates the tmp folder, it is still created on the host. Effectively what I want is the tmp only to exist in the guests file system

Comment: so your goal with to prevent the host from seeing the file in a container. this is not possible because even if you can, whoever can run `docker` can just `exec` in to the container and see everything.

Comment: The problem is that rails creates a tmp dir which contains the current process id of the server. If the server has been running previously or the container exits unexpected, this folder is not cleared making a new docker process unable to start

Answer (score 2):

The right way to exclude folder from container but still be able to login into container and inspect files (I'm talking about development environment):

```
volumes:
  - ./app-backend:/srv/www/app
  - type: tmpfs
    target: /srv/www/app/var/
```

So my ./var folder **is excluded** from syncing but when I log into the container - cache and log files are there.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/, a quote:

> a tmpfs mount is temporary, and only persisted in the host memory.
> When the container stops, the tmpfs mount is removed, and files
> written there won’t be persisted.

This works for:

- Docker version 20.10.13
- Docker Compose version v2.3.3