# .dockerignore is not ignoring listed folders and files

Tags: docker

This is how my folder structure looks like

```
- myapp
-- public
-- other_dirs
-- docker // contain all the Dockerfiles and configuration files etc
-- vendor
-- .gitignore
-- .dockerignore
-- README.md
```

In the Dockerfile I use I have this in order to copy all my app within the container

```
FROM php:7.1-apache-stretch

COPY . /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

And this is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        image: myapp
        build:
             context: .
             dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        networks:
            - appnet
```

and this is how my `.dockerignore` file looks like

```
.git
.gitignore
vendor/
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` and then `exec` to enter my app container, if I do `ls -lah` I can still see in the list the folders and files I have added in the `.dockerignore` file. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your `docker-compose.yml` file to the question?

Comment: Try `vendor/*` and `.git/*`

Comment: Nope, still showing in my container.

Comment: Also added the docker-compose file on the topic

Comment: The .dockerignore file should be in `/var/www/html` since that's where you're copying from, is that where it is?

Comment: @ClickUpvote when I run `ls -la` in the app container I see the dockerignore file in my WORKDIR. Not understand, is this supposed not to be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the files because you are mounting the volume in the directory.
To fix it, please take a look at: [Make docker-compose ignore folder within volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570499/make-docker-compose-ignore-folder-within-volume)

Comment: Not sure I understand, so I need to have to empty directories locally and do something like this `./empty-vendor:/var/www/html/vendor` in my docker compose file?

Comment: When you ADD or COPY, docker will look at the .dockerignore, but when you mount a volume, all files will be added. Are you sure you need to mount the volume for the whole folder? If you can mount only specific folders of `.` the problem will also be fixed

Comment: Can you create a blacklist of folders and files you don't want to mount within `.` in the docker-compose file? Some thing like `- !./vendor:/var/www/html/vendor`, `- !.git:/var/www/html/.git` and add this after `- .:/var/www/html`

Comment: It would only be possible for folders, like the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder/37898591 . I recommend you changing your folder architecture so you can have a folder like `html/` to mount, at the same level of the files you want to ignore