# Docker Ignore is not woking well with docker compose and my file structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'am setting up a new dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. I'll below show  first my file structure with rails and I want to use a new .dockerignore to ignore **node_modules**, **.git** .

my **docker version** is: **Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4**

my **docker-compose.yml** than I use is **v3**

**Root Directory**

```
- Gemfile
- app
- bin
- cable
- db
- config
- lib
- node_modules
- public
- vendor
- docker
  - app
    - Dockerfile
- .git
- .gitignore
- .dockerignore
- docker-compose.yml
```

**docker/app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1
ARG RAILS_ROOT
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
COPY . .
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: &build_core
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
      args:
        - APP_NAME=myappname
        - RAILS_ROOT=/var/www/${APP_NAME}_web
        - RAILS_ENV=development
        - RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
        - RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true
        - BUNDLE_OPTIONS=
        - NPM_OPTIONS=
    image: custom-web:1.0
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/${APP_NAME}_web
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ROOT: "/var/www/${APP_NAME}_web"
```

**.dockerignore**

```
.git/
node_modules/
```

I built my image with the next command

```
docker-compose build app
```

When I look at the container, the file files are still copying to my container

maybe is the context or where I should put my .dockerignore also I put my .dockerignore into docker/app/.dockerignore and I have the same problem.

Comment: "When I look at the container, the file files are still copying to my container" : how do you start the container to check this (`docker run [...] custom-web:1.0` or `docker-compose up/start app`)?

Comment: I start the container with: ```docker-compose run app ls -la``` and  I can see the files yet.

Comment: I see, the problem may come from the volume you have defined. Check my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

At build time, the directive `COPY . .` (inside the `Dockerfile`) correctly copies all files not listed in `.dockerignore` in `$RAILS_ROOT` (inside the image). No problem here (check that by running `docker run --rm custom-web:1.0 ls -al`).

But here you run `docker-compose` to start the container, and you have defined a volume :

```
volumes:
    - .:/var/www/${APP_NAME}_web
```

That means that files from the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` are shared between the host and the container. That's why you find all files (even those listed in `.dockerignore`) in `$RAILS_ROOT` (workdir of `custom-web:1.0` image) after starting the container via `docker-compose`.

If you really need to share files between your host and the container (via a volume), I'll suggest you to mount the current directory in another location than the one specified in your `Dockerfile`, like :

```
volumes:
    - .:/${APP_NAME}_web
```

Otherwise, using `COPY . .` and a volume is redundant here.

Comment: Great this is awesome, thanks a lot this is the solution! and excuse me I am starting with docker!

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same problem with `docker build`, `node_modules` directories were not being ignored.

**SOLUTION**
Changing `node_modules` to `**/node_modules` inside `.dockerignore` solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

[Per this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37898591/1879728) you can mount your main directory but ignore the `node_modules` using a second anonymous volume in the `docker-compose.yml`. This allows you to mirror your directory but the container should keep its own node_modules.

```
volumes:
  - .:/var/www/${APP_NAME}_web
  - /var/www/${APP_NAME}_web/node_modules/
```