# How to exclude subfolders when using volume?

Tags: docker, volume, mount

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginxtest
    container_name: nginxtest-container
    volumes:
      - "$PWD:/apps"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Above is my compose file.

I have created dummy file in that directory. If I want to ignore or exclude changes made in one file and all other files should be reflecting the change as it is, how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to mount $PWD but want to exclude `$PWD/template`, you can use this.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginxtest-container
    volumes:
      -  "/apps/template"
      - "$PWD:/apps"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

`/apps/template` creates a separate space. Anything in `$PWD/template` will not be mirrored in the container, anything in `/apps/template` will also not be reflected on the host.

Comment: thanks ,this works when template is a folder , file inside template will not be reflected to the container but if i want to ignore a file let consider template is a file ,what to do then ..?