# How to "hide" the node_modules-dir from the host when mounting a src-dir in docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-modules, mounted-volumes

I use `docker-compose` (version `1.24.0`) to run my Node.js App inside a container. In development mode I mount my `src` volume, but I'd like the container to use a `node_modules` directory that is not created on my host, just locally within the container.

Excerpt from my docker-compose

```
volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/app
command:
 - /bin/sh
 - -c
 - |
   npm install
   npm run dev
```

Is there a way to make the sub-directory `/usr/src/app/node_modules` local to the container and have `npm install` not create and populate the directory `./node_modules` on the host?

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder) posted on Stackoverflow, somehow the directory `node_modules` still gets created and populated on my host upon running `npm install .` inside the container. I used the following modified `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/app
  - /usr/src/app/node_modules
command:
 - /bin/sh
 - -c
 - |
   npm install
   npm run dev
```

I even tried using named volumes like so:

```
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules

volumes:
- node_modules
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder)

Comment: @leopal: This is _not_ a duplicate of [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder). I tried that solution and it did not work for me, even though I am using latest `docker-compose`.

Comment: Does your volumes: - node_modules compile without complaining?
Try volumes:
 node_modules:

(drop the - in front, add : after)