# Why dotenv is not loaded in docker but works fine in host machine?

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables, npm-install, dotenv

I want to build an Docker image which will run my node.js application. I'm using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm package to store environment variables. The `.env` is located in the root of the project. When I run my npm script which starts the application (`npm run start_in_docker`) from host machine everything works perfectly. However when I run Docker container I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/server/main.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN apk add --update python
RUN apk add --update vim
RUN apk add --update sqlite
RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm install --unsafe-perm=true sqlite3 -g
RUN npm install pm2 -g
# run node-gyp to build sqlite3
RUN cd /usr/src/app/node_modules/sqlite3 && npm run install
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file which runs the Dockerfile above:

```
version: '3'
services:
  appstore-bl-server:
    container_name: appstore-bl-server-production
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/app"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - appstore-net
    command: npm run start_in_docker

networks:
  appstore-net:
    driver: bridge
```

This is my package.json scripts section:

```
"scripts": {
    "start_in_docker": "NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=server:*,classes:*,middleware,utils node src/server/main.js",
}
```

and this is how I require `dotenv` in my main.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

I tried specifying the absolute path in `('dotenv').config()` but it didn't work. What's strange is that if I run the container shell (`docker run -it myimage /bin/ash`) and then run `npm run start_in_docker` it will also work. `dotenv` is in my package.json of course.

Comment: Is `dotenv` in your `dependencies` or `devDependencies` in `package.json`?

Comment: @braza it's in my dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is caused by:

```
volumes:
  - ".:/usr/src/app"
```

in your docker-compose file. This links the current dir to the app folder, meaning everything including `node_modules` is replaced.

Try removing the volumes from `docker-compose` and see if it works.

When you run `docker run -it myimage /bin/sh` it will not link the volume, meaning it will be using the correct `node_modules`, which is why it works when using that.

Comment: indeed this solved the issue! Thank you! but if I still want to have a volume can I "protect" somehow .env from being overwritten?

Comment: You could try creating a volume just to the files you want to overwrite, e.g. `  - "./src:/usr/src/app/src", or there is an answer here if you just want to persist certain files or folders like `node_modules` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601156/1021714

Comment: just to understand: because of the `volumes` in docker-compose, when I'd build the image the contents of `/usr/src/app` inside the container would be overwritten by the contents of host's `/usr/src/app`?

Comment: Yes, but only when you run it, not when you build it. So the files won't exist in the docker image, which is why your `docker run` command worked, but when you run it with your current `docker-compose` config, it will mount the volumes at runtime and overwrite `/usr/src/app` with the contents on the host.