# Syncing a Node Docker Container with Docker-Compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Has anyone dealt with syncing files with a docker container running nodemon via docker-compose? I’ve done it with PHP, but this Node project explodes when I do that (as opposed to COPY  in the Dockerfile)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9229
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install -g nodemon
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  api:
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    command: "npm run debug && tail -f /dev/null"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "mongo:/data/db"
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9001:9229"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - network
volumes:
  mongo:

networks:
  network: {}
```

And *part* of package.json (for reference):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha ./tests/controllers/*.test.js --timeout 10000 --exit",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0 server.js",
    "build-docs": "node ./swagger.js"
},
```

Step debugging, etc. and everything else works just fine, but the files are *copies* in the container (per the `Dockerfile`).

When I add something like:

```
- "./:/usr/src/app"
```

to the `docker-compose.yml` file for the `api` container, I get an error for bcrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was with `node_modules`, and [made a named volume per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601156/808870) in order to ignore it, but persist it.