# How to ignore files or directories within bind-mount volume in docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way to ignore some files or directories within volume of type bind-mount?

I would like to ignore for example all `bin` and `obj` directories within my solution. The issue is that I have dozens of `bin` and `obj` folders in my project. I have tried with `glob` pattern but is seems not working with `yaml` files.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  service-1:
    image: some-img:latest
    container_name: some-name
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ../src/:/app/src/ # bind-mount
    - /app/src/project1/bin # AS-IS
    - /app/src/project1/obj # AS-IS
    - /app/src/project2/bin # AS-IS
    - /app/src/project2/obj # AS-IS
    - /app/src/*/bin # TO-BE (not working)
    - /app/src/*/obj # TO-BE (not working)
    - '/app/src/*/obj' # TO-BE (not working)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I know how to ignore single file/directory by typing their path explicitly, but I would like to know how to ignore all specific files/directories without typing them explicitly. For exmaple ignore all bin folders from entire project