# Docker container works from Dockerfile but get next: not found from docker-compose container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, dockerfile

I am having an issue with my docker-compose configuration file. My goal is to run a Next.js app with a docker-compose file and enable hot reload.

Running the Next.js app from its Dockerfile works but hot reload does not work.
Running the Next.js app from the docker-compose file triggers an error: `/bin/sh: next: not found` and I was not able to figure what's wrong...

#### `Dockerfile`: (taken from Next.js' documentation website)

[Notice it's a multistage build however, I am only referencing the `builder` stage in the docker-compose file.]

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install # --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:18-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3001

ENV PORT 3001

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
  backend:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${MYAPP_DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: builder
    command: yarn dev
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    expose:
      - "3001"
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      FRONTEND_BUILD: ${FRONTEND_BUILD}
      PORT: 3001
```

#### `package.json`:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
  }
}
```

When calling `yarn dev` from `docker-compose.yml` it actually calls `next dev` and that's when it triggers the error `/bin/sh: next: not found`. However, running the container straight from the `Dockerfile` works and does not lead to this error.

#### [Update]:

If I remove the `volume` attribute from my `docker-compse.yml` file, I don't get the `/bin/sh: next: not found` error and the container runs however, I now don't get the hot reload feature I am looking for. Any idea why the volume is messing up with the `/bin/sh next` command?

Comment: You could run `docker-compose up -d backend` to start everything except the frontend in this setup, then use ordinary Node without Docker to develop the frontend.  That would let you delete the problematic `volumes:` block.

Comment: @DavidMaze it's a solution however, at this point, I'm trying to figure out wrong with my docker-compose config because I simply don't get why adding the `volumes` parameter breaks things

Comment: It overwrites absolutely everything in the image, including its `node_modules` directory, and replaces it with different content from the host (possibly built for a different OS, or maybe missing `node_modules` entirely).

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because your local filesystem is being mounted over what is in the docker container. Your docker container does build the node modules in the `builder` stage, but I'm guessing you don't have the node modules available in your local file system.

To see if this is what is happening, on your local file system, you can do a `yarn install`. Then try running your container via docker again. I'm predicting that this will work, as `yarn` will have installed `next` locally, and it is actually your local file system's node modules that will be run in the docker container.

One way to fix this is to volume mount everything *except* the node modules folder. Details on how to do that: [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder)

So in your case, I believe you can add a line to your compose file:

```
frontend:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - ./frontend/node_modules # <-- try adding this!
    ...
```

That should allow the docker container's `node_modules` to not be overwritten by any volume mount.

Answer (score 2):

You can also parse this to the `volumes` directive:

```yaml
frontend:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules # <-- creates the node_modules in frontend path
      - /app/.next # <-- creates the .next folder in frontend path
    ...
```