# Exclude sub-folder when mounting host to volume docker

Tags: docker

I have dockerfile looks like :

```
RUN set -ex \
    && mkdir /home/app/cache-pool \
    && chown -R app:app /home/app/cache-pool \
    && mkdir /home/app/my-app \
    && chown -R app:app /home/app/my-app;
WORKDIR /home/app/my-app

RUN rm -vfr /home/app/cache-pool/*
RUN ln -s /home/app/cache-pool /home/app/my-app/public/page_cache
```

Exclude .dockerignore

```
/public/page_cache
```

I'm using docker compose to run the containers and mounting source code from host

```
services:
  app:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/app/my-app
```

based on that all sub-directories under `/home/app/my-app` will replace by host include `/home/app/my-app/public/..` also will break a created symlink on image even I create another volume to ignore it
ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37898591/1297435

```
services:
  app:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/app/my-app
      - /home/app/my-app/public/page_cache
```

Do I need to re-symlink on docker compose entry point or any best way not to break symlink even I mount the source from host on volume?

Comment: You can't really do this (the linked question suggests a popular hack around the Node `node_modules` directory).  I'd delete the `volumes:` entirely: use the code built into the image, not from somewhere else.  A previous question you asked put the page cache in a different directory outside of the application source tree (IIRC `/home/app/page-cache`, not under `/home/app/my-app`) and that's also a good choice.

Comment: @DavidMaze the problem on my prev question I found it because that replace by host when mounting the volume, so I just need to find another way to don't replace the `page_cache` under `/home/app/my-app/public`